# Lagrange's four-square Implementation

Tags: algorithm, numbers

I am learning about [Lagrange theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange's_four-square_theorem) , According to which every number can be represent a sum of square , But how do i implement this algorithm , i have search the web but i could not find any relevant material on this.
 Can anyone help me implement this algorithm or provide some reference ?

Comment: how big can your number can get?

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like there's an easy answer for this.  Here are some references I think will help, though.

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/483101/rabin-and-shallit-algorithm

https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/2988/how-fast-can-we-find-all-four-square-combinations-that-sum-to-n